# Search in large taxonomy to assign in admin panel Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I built a custom taxonomy that contains brands, models and years of cars, this is ready. The problem is that I am now entering the products to "woocommerce" and in each product I have to look for the make, model and year in the box to assign and the list is huge. I want there to be some search so that it is not so much work to enter each product.

Is there a plugin for the administrator that will allow me to find the make and model more easily?

I tried it with the "Admin taxonomy autocomplete" plugin and it no longer works. It was the ideal solution.

link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-taxonomy-autocomplete/

I leave the picture about what I want.[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XK2M.png)

Thanks Friends.

Comment: Try with a CSV post importer, some allow to assign terms and post meta values

Comment: Thanks for replying, maybe you will not explain me well. The data are already entered in the taxonomy, what I want is to make it easier to assign each brand, model and year, that list is huge and for worse, it messes me up. In the background assign it easier so that it does not complicate me so much.

Or is it possible that I can import each product into a csv with the taxonomies completed? Is there something for that?